# How do a hash property in a parent class controller be mixed with a property with the same name in a subclass controller

Tags: ember.js

The `actions` hash in controllers [inherit](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Controller.html#property_actions) action handlers from parent classes ... how can i mimic this behavior with others hashes in controllers?

For example: I have a object named `sockets` in a parent controller with some content inside. When i make a subclass with a object also named `sockets` ... i wanna *mix the two contents* of objects and not overwrite with the child class `sockets` object...

I wanna this (the same behavior of `actions` hash):

**parent class**

```
export default Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  sockets: {
    hi: function() {};
  }
});
```

**child class**

```
export default ParentController.extend({
  sockets: {
    bye: function() {};
  }
});

ChildClassController.create().get('sockets.hi'); // Exists
ChildClassController.create().get('sockets.bye'); // Exists
```

First i try with a mixin, but the content of hash in mixin was overwrited by the content of hash in controller.
After i try use the [concatenatedProperties](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Controller.html#property_concatenatedProperties) ... but this creates a array with the two hashes inside ...

Answer (score 1):

Resolved by Wildhoney in https://github.com/Wildhoney/EmberSockets/issues/43.

One solution could be to implement the init method and merge the two objects yourself:

```
concatenatedProperties: ['sockets'],
init: function() {
  var that = this,
      sockets = that.get('sockets'),
      merged = Ember.$.extend.apply( Ember.$, sockets );

  that.set('sockets', merged);
  that._super();
},
```